# return response from a module from a call

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, axios, last.fm

So i have a function in a module, This is the Index file

```
const track = require('./components/trackPlays')
const Plays = track.Plays(username, expT ,expA )
```

this is the module file.

```js
const axios = require('axios');
const keys = require('../../../../keys/lfmconfig.json')

const Plays = (f,t,a) => {
  const requestURL = `http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.getInfo&api_key=${keys.apikey}&username=${f}&artist=${a}&track=${t}&format=json`
  axios.get(requestURL)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data.track.userplaycount) 
    return response.data.track.userplaycount
  })
}


exports.Plays = Plays
```

I want to use the value response.data.track.userplaycount in my index file but when i try to return it, it just returns undefined

Comment: You use promise chaining. `const Plays = track.Plays(username, expT ,expA )`should be "awaited" or made "then" able.

Comment: @madflow how would i make it then able? Thanks!

Comment: `const Plays = track.Plays(username, expT ,expA );`  and `Plays.then(() => {})`